# How do I merge and add up columns in R?

Tags: r, merge

I have an issue in R I cannot fix, so I'm asking for help here. I want to merge three columns into one, but haven't found a way to do so. Let's say it looks like this table:

```
Time H C W K
0    1 2 0 5
1    5 2 1 1
2    0 1 2 2
```

How do I turn it into this table:

```
Time G K
0    3 5
1    8 1
2    3 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try this:

```
#Code
newdf <- data.frame(df[,1,drop=F],G=rowSums(df[,-c(1,5)]),df[,5,drop=F])
```

Output:

```
  Time G K
1    0 3 5
2    1 8 1
3    2 3 2
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(Time = 0:2, H = c(1L, 5L, 0L), C = c(2L, 2L, 1L
), W = 0:2, K = c(5L, 1L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Also a shortcut instead of placing each variable and improving the answer of **@KarthikS** can be using `c_across()`:

```
library(dplyr)
#Code2
newdf <- df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(G = sum(c_across(H:W))) %>% select(Time, G, K)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Rowwise: 
   Time     G     K
  <int> <int> <int>
1     0     3     5
2     1     8     1
3     2     3     2
```

Comment: Again, I'm new to R so I have 0 clue what any of your first code means. What do the drop=F stand for? And the c -1,5? Note that K is a stand in for c.20 other columns in the real dataset and not a column on its own.

Comment: @W178 drop is used to keep the structure of column of name, the -c(1,5) is used to omit that cols from the sum, you can modify and play around that if you have more variables.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try the code below

```
subset(within(df, G <- rowSums(cbind(H, C, W))), select = -c(H, C, W))
```

giving

```
  Time K G
1    0 5 3
2    1 1 8
3    2 2 3
```

---

or a `data.table` option

```
> setDT(df)[, .(Time, G = rowSums(cbind(H, C, W)), K)][]
   Time G K
1:    0 3 5
2:    1 8 1
3:    2 3 2
```

Comment: This I can work with, but the error given is Error in: x[j], only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `transmute`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
     transmute(Time, G = rowSums(select(., H:W)), K)
#  Time G K
#1    0 3 5
#2    1 8 1
#3    2 3 2
```